# When Should The Following Tests Be Run

Tags: self-study, t-test, f-test, paired-data, sign-test

What are the assumptions behind each of the following types of tests (i.e. what are the prerequisites to running each test).

1. Paired-t
2. Sign
3. Two-Sample t
4. Pooled Two-Sample t
5. Two Proportions
6. F

I really am getting confused seeing what would warrant one over the other given criteria like (normality, variance, sample size etc.) Any help would be appreciated.

(Note: This is for a class assignment)

Comment: This seems to be rather similar to your previous question, though it is perhaps a better fit. When you say 'F', which (of many) F tests do you mean? F test for variances? F test in ANOVA? one of the other F tests? By distinguishing between items 3 and 4, does 3. imply a Welch-Satterthwaite test, or something else? Why include those tests and not something like, say a signed-rank test or a rank-sum (Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney) test?

Comment: Yes I apologize. I do not mean to keep posting the same question. To be honest with you, the assignment I have does not say. Here is a link to the writeup of the assignment. I for one think the assignment is quite obscure. http://ge.tt/5P11xH81/v/0?c

Comment: I tagged it as self-study which was the closest tag to homework I could get.

Comment: I note that in the assignment, it says "*Each of these comes with assumptions and rules-of-thumb on robustness (sample size targets). These were covered in the Chapter 7 & 8 lectures.*" and it goes on to say where to find that information --- why *precisely* is the information there on the assumptions and rules of thumb you're being expected to apply insufficient?

Comment: I will edit my question noting this is for an assignment. Here is the powerpoint he references. I don't believe it gives the assumptions to all of these tests. http://ge.tt/5a8T0I81/v/0

Comment: I didn't ask to see what you were told (I don't want to do your assignment). I asked you to identify exactly how what you were told was insufficient (I want to know precisely what you need in addition to what you already know, rather than supply information it would take a small book to answer). Whoever wrote the assignment believes the information was sufficient - why are they wrong?

Comment: The powerpoint contains the extent of my knowledge of the assumptions behind each of these tests. There is only straightforward instructions for when two proportions should be used (slide 15). I simply just want to know what requirements must be met by the data in order to warrant the use of one of these tests.

Comment: After a quick glance at the ppt I see that several of my previous requests for clarification (either here or elsewhere) are covered in those notes. When you said "*To be honest with you, the assignment I have does not say.*" ... well in fact it pretty much *does*, since it points to a document that answers many of those questions (and a quick google search should be enough to cover the few you might not be certain of). You should address those requests for clarification rather than make unnecessary work for people attempting to help you.

Comment: I am really sorry that I am appearing incompetent here. This is the first stat class I've ever taken. Given this powerpoint, I cannot figure out the assumptions necessary to determine which of these tests should be used. If you can, could you please explain your understandings to me.

Comment: If you have some specific questions, perhaps. Please compare, test by test, what information has been supplied and identify particular questions where the explanations fail to give you enough information. As an example of what I said about requests for clarification, those notes clearly identify which F-test this is for.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily disagree with the assessment that the assignment is problematical in various ways (in some cases, bordering on egregious), but it is certainly possible to make a deal of progress on what the person writing the question wants to receive.

Comment: I agree with @Glen_b; you can pretty much answer the question by pulling information from the ppt and some deduction, e.g., when the  slide says, as far as I can remember, "the F test is not robust against deviations from normality", that's basically telling you that normality is an important assumption of the F test, and so on.  I doubt the professor is expecting you to provide an answer that's well beyond what he/she went over in class, so I'd just play follow the leader here and regurgitate what's in the ppt and any supplemental notes you took.

Comment: @jbowman exactly! I expect there's a few points where it's less obvious, but some progress can still be made and more specific questions identified.

Comment: I will see if I can come up with better questions for the community. Until then, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this doesn't necessarily cover the assumptions as required for the assignment*, it may well be worth laying out some things briefly for these common tests (though in most cases, a judicious use of the search function here on CrossValidated will yield the required information).

*(for which see your notes)

There are two main questions to address:

(i) What assumptions are necessary to derive the distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis

(ii) Which of those assumptions are more critical or less critical?

I should probably also add some discussion on the inadvisability of performing these tests only after performing hypothesis test of one or more of their assumptions, but briefly, it seems to be fairly clear that the tests done conditional on such preliminary testing *do not have their nominal properties*, and several papers advise that when there's no clear reason to think they're satisfied *a priori*, it's generally better to simply do whatever would be appropriate when they are not satisfied. [There isn't an option for you, though, since you're required to do so.]

**1. [Paired-t test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Paired_samples)**

This is a test for paired (matched) samples when applied to the differences (that the population mean pair difference is zero); it also applies when testing a single sample against some hypothesized mean.

Assumptions:

a) independence across pair-differences (not within pairs; they're dependent)

b) constant variance of pair-differences

c) normality of pair-differences

The more critical assumptions are independence and constant variance.

It's difficult to test independence without a specific form of dependence to check for. If you have observations over time, obviously one should be concerned about dependence over time.

Equality of variance across pair differences is tricky to check
for without a specific alternative (one possibility is to see whether absolute size of
difference is related to the average of the two measurements - e.g. to check whether
${|y_i - x_i|}$ is related to ${(y_i+x_i)}/2$, though the $\frac{1}{2}$ could be omitted); that's one reasonably common way in which it might tend to be violated.

The normality assumption matters in small samples, and much less so in large samples; in very large samples, you may be able to just about ignore normality as long as the other assumptions hold.

2. **[Sign test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_test)**

This is another paired/matched samples test that is also suitable as a one-sample test. It is basically a test of the null hypothesis that the population median of the pair-differences is zero. If suitable additional assumptions are made it can also be suitable as a test of means (specifically, if the assumption that the population mean is the same as the population median in the distribution of pair differences).

Main assumptions:

a) independence across pair-differences (not within pairs; they're dependent)

b) continuous distribution of pair differences; this avoids the issue of the 
    difference being exactly zero (though suitable adjustment to the procedure 
    can be made if it's not the case)

Again, independence is important, but it's difficult to test without a specific form
of dependence. If you have a time series, obviously one should be concerned 
about dependence over time.

Null hypothesis under the assumptions yields a binomial distribution for the number
of positive differences, but the normal approximation may be used if sample sizes aren't small.

3. **[Two-Sample t test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Equal_or_Unequal_sample_sizes.2C_unequal_variances)**

This is the [two-sample t-test with the Welch-Satterthwaite approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t_test) to the degrees of freedom chisquare approximation for the unpooled variance estimate. It 
is for testing equality of population means for independent samples.

Basic assumptions:

a) independence both within and between groups

b) common normal distributions within each population, but not necessarily equal variance across them

Moderate non-normality is not particularly crucial in moderate samples, and hardly matters in large samples. It can matter in very small samples.

4. **[Pooled Two-Sample t test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Unequal_sample_sizes.2C_equal_variance)**

This is the two-sample t-test with the additional assumption of equality of variance. It is for testing equality of population means for independent samples.

Basic assumptions:

a) independence both within and between groups

b) equality of population variance across groups

c) common normal distributions within each population

Moderate non-normality is not particularly crucial in moderate samples, and hardly matters in large samples. It can matter in very small samples. As before independence and equality of variance matters more, but in equal-sized samples, the equality of variance matters less.

5. **[Two sample Proportions test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing#Common_test_statistics)**

This is for testing equality of proportions between two independent samples.

It assumes:

a) independence, and

b) (within groups), constant success probability.

There are two versions, the pooled and the unpooled versions (see the above link which includes both in the list of common test statistics). Either is suitable under the null hypothesis, but you should at least be aware which one is being performed.

In large enough samples (large enough to apply the normal approximation, say), moderate deviations from constant success probability assumption is less crucial than independence.

6. **[F test for equality of variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test_of_equality_of_variances)**

This is for testing equality of variance in two samples.

It assumes:

a) independence (within and across groups)

b) normality

It is very sensitive to both assumptions and is generally not recommended. There are better choices.

There are some situations when you might need to decide between 1. and 2. with paired samples (watch out for the differences between them), since none of the others are paired. You might need to decide between 3. and 4. (hint for people in a conundrum: if you're in doubt about whether the variance might differ substantially, use the unpooled one, though if sample sizes are equal the decision is less critical). 5. and 6. really aren't competing with anything in that list; if you're testing independent proportions, only one of the above tests really fits; similarly if you're testing variances, only one of the tests in the list fits.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this very complete answer. I has helped me a lot with the assignment.

Comment: Julian; you'll need to review the notes again, there are important clues to the approach you'll be expected to use there. Some may not agree with my answers (though my answers may be more useful beyond the assignment)